# How can I interlace two images using ImageMagick?

Tags: image, graphics, imagemagick, interlacing

I have 2 images of the same size, called `image1.png` and `image2.png`. In ImageMagick, is there any way to merge the two images by taking the odd lines from `image1.png` and merge with the even line from `image2.png` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, make alternate rows transparent:

```
# Make red test image
convert -size 300x200 xc:red red.png
```

[image]

```
# Make blue test image
convert -size 300x200 xc:blue blue.png
```

[image]

```
# Merge with alternate lines made transparent
convert red.png \( blue.png -alpha on -channel A -fx 'j%2' \) -composite result.png
```

[image]

Or, an alternative way of thinking about it is to load both images and then choose pixels from either the first (`u`) or the second (`v`) depending on the row:

```
convert red.png blue.png -fx 'j%2 ? u : v' result.png
```

[image]

On Windows, these two come out as:

```
REM Do Windows style commands
convert red.png ^( blue.png -alpha on -channel A -fx "j%2" ^) -composite result.png
```

and

```
REM Windows style
convert red.png blue.png -fx "j%2 ? u:v" result.png
```

Comment: I'm using command prompt on Windows for ImageMagick so I guess there are some compatibility problems.
The first method doesn't work. Using backslash in cmd results in error.
I tried to use your alternative method, albeit replace red and blue with my images' names, and the CPU shoots up too 100% for a few seconds, which may seem normal as for rendering image but then no output file.

Comment: On Windows, you need to replace single quotes with double quotes. You may also need a caret (`^`) before brackets and percent signs, or to double percent signs.

Comment: I have done some Windowsy versions at the end for you.

Comment: Works like a charm
Thank you

Comment: Pleasure! Good luck with your project.